# Wireshark STOMP protocol dissector

Tags: wireshark, stomp, wireshark-dissector

I have a an spring app that talks to a rabbitmq server.
The message exchange is occuring trough STOMP protocol.
My question is why is not my STOMP message not decoded.
I have uploaded and install the STOMP plugin for it.
https://github.com/ficoos/wireshark-stomp-plugin (stomp.lua)

And still i see  only i susspect the UTF-8 encoded message, that is not beein represented propertly.
An image showing the probelm

Is there a way i can recode/discect exactlly what is inside the message?

[image]

[image]

Addition 25 June 2015: I thing i found my answer i.e. the web socket protocol has something called "masking key", which basically says that the traffic from client to server should be encoded with that random masking key value. As far as i understand that is done in order to avoid problems with proxy's. Now i believe that the problem is related to the wireshark implementation i.e. wireshark decodes the payload correctly i.e. the  clear text part of the Payload field is to be found in the field Unmask Payload, but when following the TCP Streap the UI most likely takes not the Unmask Payload value but the "Payload" value i.e. the values before the xor of the masking key is applied.
I would really appreciate if someone that knows wireshark can confirm that. Thus that will meant that's a bug or feature (i am not sure) in Wireshark

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.3

Addition J Jul.

Added link to an example trace file
https://yadi.sk/d/E1a6bPhfhfUAf

Comment: According to the spec, a Stomp CONNECTED frame does not have a message body. Can you try to capture a SEND or MESSAGE frame (with text payload) in Wireshark?

Comment: I did  i am uploading the wireshark picture to the question above

Comment: In the picture above is the MESSAGE frame i do see that what the client is sending to the server is gibrish. Is there any way to decode this? I meant the responce is readable with that i mean the  {"content: "Hello, aaaaaaassss!"}

Comment: @mjn any ideas why this is not working? or maybe this is already function as designed i.e. it should be binary although I thought STOMP is a text based protocol

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the pink text is what you want to see "decrypted"? Actually I can only guess that this is data which does not belong to the STOMP conversation, but to the WebSocket protocol. Could it be that Websocket wraps the STOMP data with leading / trailing information? (In this case I would also add the websocket tag to the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the `stomp.lua` Lua plugin you gave a link for on github, it looks like it was only written to handle STOMP messages running natively on TCP, and even for that you'd have to set the TCP port number for it to decode, in Edit->Preferences->Protocol->STOMP (or right-click and do "Decode as...").

But your screenshot is of a websocket connection, and yes that uses a masking key... but Wireshark *can* actually de-mask it. Wireshark will show you both the masked and unmasked payload in the packet details pane. But the stomp.lua plugin won't dissect anything inside of that, for the reason I said earlier.

If you want help getting stomp.lua to be usable in a websocket, I'd suggest posting the question on [ask.wireshark.org](https://ask.wireshark.org), or emailing [wireshark-users@wireshark.org](https://www.wireshark.org/mailman/listinfo/wireshark-users). In either case, it would help a lot if you could put a sample capture file (like the one in your screenshot) somewhere and providing a link to it.

Comment: i created the question in https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/43861/wireshark-stomp-protocol-dissector as you suggested. I am not sure that i understand the logic behind stomp running on TCP as i do see the traffic from server to client decoded in the UI. most likely this is really the masking key problem but let us wait till someone on ask.wireshark.org comments on that

Comment: i have just added a example trace file

Comment: The logic for the plugin only dissecting STOMP on native TCP is that is what the STOMP protocol spec says STOMP should be run over.  STOMP is itself an HTTP-like protocol, and can run natively on TCP just like HTTP and other protocols do.  See https://stomp.github.io for details.

Running it over websocket is not following the spec for STOMP, as described at http://jmesnil.net/stomp-websocket/doc/